# Rails 3.2 Limit to length of URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-string

Is there a limit to the length of a url in Rails apps?  I have a bunch of query parameters that I am trying to attach to a URL, and, at some point, I simply get a `!! Invalid request` error in the logs.  This error appears when I try to attach something like 400 integers as a query parameter.

If there is a limit, is there a way around it, or do I need to switch to `Post` methods?

**EDIT**

Is there a Rails specific limitation that may be less than the HTTP standard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell from your question if you are encountering the limit with a browser, or going through a specific web server, but that can have it's limits.  I don't know if Rails has a limit, but apache httpd does.

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html